Definition of \descriptionlabel
I just read about the different definitions of the lists in LaTeX. I cannot find the source but it seems to me that the definition of the command \descriptionlabel is something like {\hspace\labelsep\textbf{#1}}, because I've seen the redefinition of this command as something like renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{{\hspace{\labelsep}\textsc{#1}}} (in Unofficial LaTeX2e reference manual), or something just changing the \textsc{#1} to \textit{#1}, etc. Now my first question is :
(1) is this the exact source definition of \descriptionlabel ?
If so, here comes my second qustion :
(2) I cannot understand why the part \hspace\labelsep is laid before \textbf{#1}, since this space obvisously stretches after the label and before the text right ?
However with the redefinition just as mentioned above, everything seems to go well: no indent before the label, some space between the label and the text... And I've also tried to replace the \labelsep with \labelwidth (or their multiplications like 2\labelsep, 2\labelwidth), or moves this space part after the font part, nothing changes. But when I set another length like .25\linewidth, or 2em, an indentation appears before the label if the space part is before the font part, or the labelsep increases if the space part is after the font part.
I wonder if it is the underlying definition of the description list which causes this phenomenon, or that is just a strange bug ? I submit here a MWE for you to just test the phenomenon I described above.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[A] a
\end{description}

\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace{\labelsep}\textbf{#1}} % nothing changes
% \renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace{\labelwidth}\textbf{#1}} % nothing changes
% \renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\textbf{#1}\hspace{\labelsep}} % nothing changes
% \renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace{2em}\textbf{#1}} % an indentation appears before the label
% \renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\textbf{#1}\hspace{2em}} % the labelsep increases

\begin{description}
    \item[A] a
\end{description}

\endocument


welcome! latexdef \descriptionlabel returns \descriptionlabel: macro:#1->\hspace \labelsep \normalfont \bfseries #1.

I think the various bits of code which are invoked at the start of a list and at each \item don't really make sense in isolation. so you'd have to look at this in the context of where it is happening because latex inserts both negative and positive horizontal spaces in order to align the label. enumitem has some useful diagrams and explanation of the default lists (as well as its own extensions).

Thanks for your comment cfr. Actually this question does come from my learning of the enumitem package. It is just for understanding the underlying definition, which is not so important for the practice I think... By the way, I've seen your command latexdef \descriptionlabel to look up the definition of a certain command. Could you please specify where I can use this command ? This is also a question hauting me all the time because I did not know how to look up a definition of a command, just as we use the ? sign before a command in the R.

which tex distribution are you using? for tex live, I can just use it at the command line. (I don't know for sure what this is called on windows, but I think something like 'powershell'.) on a mac, I'd use Terminal. on any other unix-ish system, I'd use whichever terminal emulator was available. you can also use texdef. (actually, I'm pretty sure latexdef just is texdef with a format specification.)

@cfr latexdef also works on windows.

you can also put \show\descriptionlabel in your document and tex will stop to show you the meaning. it will also put it into the log. this doesn't work well with gui editors. if you use it at https://texlive.net/run, though, the error causes the log to be displayed, so you can see the definition. latexdef is better than \show, though, as it gives more information about commands which \show doesn't break down at all.

@yannisl with miktex? I know texlive has it, but I never know what is specific and what not.

The best source to learn how LaTeX does something is its source texdoc source2e. Lists are in ltlists.dtx  Just be a bit aware lists internally use parshape and to follow up the algo takes a bit to understand it.

Thanks for this indication. I use MikTex now on Windows. I've tried to install the TexLive. However that always takes a long time without success, I don't know why... I imagin this command (la)texdef belongs to TexLive rather than MikTex ? Because I've tried in my cmd/powershell, it told me just Sorry, but (la)texdef did not succeed.

@yannisl I'm not sure I'd recommend source2e unless somebody already knows enough to know to look at it :-).

my suspicion is @yannisl means texlive, whereas my doubts concerned miktex. but I've never used miktex, so I just don't know. and I don't know how you would check on windows. (I can just about start a web browser or pdf viewer on windows, provided nothing unexpected happens.)

@cfr I think so, since my pratice has proved that with MikTex (la)texdef does not work.

@Yuanhao you should be able to install texlive, if you wanted to. (not saying you should - plenty of people prefer miktex.) but people could probably help if you needed it. (I couldn't, but plenty of others could. I think Ulrike Fischer has both distros - and more, most probably - on her machine.)

@cfr  Yes sorry, I am using windows but moved from MikTeX to texlive a few months ago.

@cfr I agree with you. I've installed TexLive on my last laptop. It had also taken a lot of time, but finally succeeded in the installation. I don't know if it is because I stay in China now which maybe block the installation of TexLive (I use the VPN though), but every time I install TexLive, the installation process will always be blocked at a certain step for hours and hours, so I always have to abort it.

LaTeX lists use \parshape and everypar to shape the item. If you familiarize yourself with these two it is easier to understand them. You can read the source using texdoc source2e. The lists are in ltlists.dtx. In my opinion the 2 most complex parts of LaTeX is the output routine followed by lists! I show the general geometry in the figure after the code.
Here is a simulation.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,calc}
\begin{document}
\parindent2em \labelsep=2em
\labelwidth=1.5cm

% Definition of myitem using \parshape
\def\myitem#1{\parshape = 1 %number lines
\labelwidth 0.8\linewidth
\leavevmode\hspace{-\labelwidth-\labelsep}\hbox{\bfseries #1\space}}

\myitem{my label text}\lipsum[3] 

\lipsum[4]

\ttfamily\meaning\descriptionlabel

\end{document}


